# crontab oracle problem in linux

Tags: database, linux, oracle, cron

I created an app which is need to run in linux started by crontab.  An error happened when it tried to connect oracle database: it returned `SQLO_INVALID_DB_HANDLE`.   But if started it manually everything is okay.

I bet there are no path-related mistakes here, because everything goes well except the connection to the Oracle database.  [Oracle8 functions](http://www.poitschke.de/libsqlora8/doc/globals.html) are used in my code.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle uses a couple of environment variables, like ORACLE_HOME, TNS_HOME, ORACLE_SID. They might be missing from your crontab environment.

Comment: +1 try wrapping your app with a shell script that sets the environment variables and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried to export my root env into crontab script, that works, thanx